# Android Studio Not Including SDK

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to setup Android Studio on a new install of Mac OS X Yosemite. I downloaded the **Android Studio Beta v0.8.14** from here: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html and upon launching it complained about not having an SDK (although the download page indicates it should include the SDK). I tried searching after installing for the SDK and can't find it (a few other posts indicate `/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk` but that location doesn't exist). Where is the SDK installed and what is required to set it up?

[image: Android SDK Location + JDK Location]

Comment: have you download android-studio-ide-135.1538390-mac.zip ?

Comment: @haresh Yes I downloaded it.

Comment: This zip only contain android studio installation applocation so you have to download SDK from here : https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html click : VIEW ALL DOWNLOADS AND SIZES and select appropriate SDK.

Comment: The same problem for the Windows package. Yet I remember I downloaded a previous version not long ago and it did has the SDK. I guess, just as James said, the download instruction needs updating.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem, the installation instructions are really misguiding.

Comment: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/install/1.0.1/android-studio-bundle-135.1641136.exe    is that bundled with sdk?

Comment: Google messed up the installation very badly. Disgusting experience of andriod sdk errors. oops

Comment: This happened on Android Studio giraffe right now after updating from some previous version. How could they not include Android SDK in Android Studio? hello?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Go to the SDK Manager and click Edit... next to the field for the location of the SDK. Then an "SDK Setup" window should display. There you can download the SDK.

Comment: This is an underrated answer. Works like a charm.

Comment: Im looking for an answer for days! It's the only thing who actually worked! thank you so much!

Comment: the problem is that I don't have the sdk installed, I can't use the sdk manager, because to do that I would need to configure the sdk path.

Comment: @ShayRibera (I haven't used it in years) but from what I remember, the SDK manager is separate from the SDK itself and is built-in to the Android Studio app, so using the SDK manager shouldn't depend on the SDK itself being installed.

Comment: yeah I downloaded the command line tools and platform-tools separately and then I was able to install everything

Answer (score 19):

**Edit:** This answer is deprecated as Android Studio seems to bundle everything since a while already.

---

#### Old answer

It seems the *android-studio-bundle* version is no longer available in the [download page](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) (instead there are only *android-studio-ide*). When you start Android Studio, it won't let you create a new projet until you configure the SDK location.

That means you have to download the SDK separately [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), extract it somewhere, and configure it on **Configure->Project Defaults->Project Structure**. After that, the SDK Manager icon will be enabled and you can download the tools you want.

[image]

Comment: This link now redirects to Android Studio download. Can't get SDK here any more

Comment: I think it's there in the section **Get just the command line tools**.

Comment: Both link get into same page now. Its shame on google to maintain such a messed up installation!

Comment: Both links don't work anymore; they redirect you to the "Download IDE"/home page

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem on Windows.  After I re-installed it a few times, I found that the SDK was installed but hidden in `C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`.

Comment: I feel like this is more of a comment

Comment: I checked in AppData to...... there is no Android folder there

Answer (score 5):

**Information for Windows**

For some reason, which I have no time to investigate, Android seems to provide, currently, the IDE and the SDK separately, while in the Dev Webpage says the opposite.

This is the "complete" (false!) tool I have just downloaded: **android-studio-ide-171.4443003-windows.exe** (SDK is missing here, note the "**ide**" in the file name).

And this is the real complete tool I had downloaded few months ago, from the same place...: **android-studio-bundle-162.3871768-windows.exe**
Note that this last one has the "**bundle**" in the file name.

Please, download the bundle (IDE+SDK) from here:

https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/install/2.3.1.0/android-studio-bundle-162.3871768-windows.exe?hl=ko

I want to suppose (¿?) that similar link you can find for Linux or macOS just Googling for it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for that. I have searched for hours to find a download with both the sdk and ide, but couldn't find it. It is strange that it is not the default download on their page

Answer (score 2):

It worked like this for me

1. Downloaded the Android Studio
2. Install Android Studio
3. Open Android Studio after installation.
4. You will get a dialog box to import settings if you already have Intellij installed on your machine. Say "**Do not Import**". Otherwise continue to next step.
5. It will ask you in the dialog box to pre-configure such as theme, path etc.
6. Just click next next...and then Finish. You will see the SDK tool will start downloading.

[image]

After installation is finished. You can find it in this path: `C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`

Comment: This is the correct answer. Choose "do not import".

Answer (score 2):

If you have ever installed Android Studio before and then removed it, it won't reinstall the SDK automatically (speculation: some Windows setting somewhere).

The solution is starting Android Studio and then
File -> Manage IDE Settings -> Restore Default Settings
This will wipe any custom settings you don't have at this point and trigger the SDK install

Comment: And if its a first instalation?

Comment: Why aren't people upvoting this answer? lol

Answer (score 1):

What Pablo wrote is misleading.

> This is the "complete" (false!) tool I have just downloaded:
>   android-studio-ide-171.4443003-windows.exe (SDK is missing here, note
>   the "ide" in the file name).

Yes, it is IDE only, but after you install this IDE and first time run it, SDK will be downloaded automatically. So there is no need to download some outdated bundles. Just use default "green button" on https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

Comment: Green button disabled for me saying I don't have prerequisites to install. I used my phone to download since i have network restrictions on PC.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu, and had previously installed Android Studio.  It was using too much space, so I deleted it.  Now when I downloaded it and started ./studio.sh, it found my previous installation configuration directory and asked to import from there.  I did, and then this problem occurred.

I put the directory `.Android Studio 3.3` in the trash and restarted `./studio.sh`, and it imported the SDK automatically for me.  That was good, because I couldn't find it where it was supposed to be according to the dialog box.  The 3.3 above is from the version of Android Studio I was installing.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, my country is forbidden from google, and my PC's time zone was set by my counrty.
after I change my timezone to another country my problem solved and android studio download SDK and nkd easily

Answer (score 0):

Re-install studio. If ANDROID_HOME is set to custom location then it will install sdk there else it will install SDK in C:\Users<user name>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

Answer (score 0):

File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Android SDK

Then click Edit

Answer (score -3):

> Note:this is a temporary fix

If you have Eclipse then you can use that SDK for emulation.

Just run the sdk manager and emulate a version of android. Then while you are asking for emulating something ie while running code it will show your emulator as online and you can even use it.

Hope this helps you.

All the Best...

Comment: @Krishan does the download no longer include the SDK? The website indicates otherwise...

Comment: i witnessed no sdk options in the studio , so using the old Emulator @KevinSylvestre