# What to do if Android SDK is not found in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I have installed Android Studio, but its not locating Android SDK, I even tried to change the directory, but in vain.

Please check the photo to see  the problem

[image: 1]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio Not Including SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26727531/android-studio-not-including-sdk)

Comment: Maybe it's permission issue. Have you tried to launch your android studio with administrator permissions? Or your disk may have some errors. Try optimizing it or try "check for disk errors" thing in properties of your disk

Answer (score 1):

go to the SDK manager just like in you image, press on edit, you'll get a setup wizard that will download the SDK files for you, if you think it's already been installed try to use the following directory

> C:\Users'your_username'\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

this is where the SDK is usually downloaded to, also note that the appdata folder is hidden in the file explorer

Comment: Yes I tried that, but then this it is showing that:

SDK emulator directory is missing

Comment: Have you tried to go there manually? Is there really that sdk folder? Maybe it can't write because there's no permission to do so? Or your antivirus maybe blocking it for "security". Try disabling it for 5 minutes and install sdk

Comment: @SyedFarazHasan when are you getting this message, have you reinstalled the SDK or you just put the path to the directory? if you just changed the path you may need to delete and reinstall the SDK from the start, and if you installed the SDK and then got this message it might be an error while download, so also deleting and reinstalling might solve the issue